# Skype Event Icons

Tags: skype

What do the Skype event icons mean? Is there a cheat sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

via [Skype forum post](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=78226):

[image]

> 1. This is a skype notification icon located in the system tray. it usually means you have an incoming event such as a call, or a missed event.
> 2. this is found on the top section of the skype main window. it lists the missed events. clicking on this will expand the window and you will see a list of all the events you have not addressed.
> 3. The yellow triangle with the exclamation mark suggests something needs your attention (in my case i have low skype out credit).
> 4. someone has sent you a file which you have accepted
> 5. this is found in the events history tab and marks a chat event.
> 6. you send someone a file and they accepted.
> 7. again in history tab an incomming call that was either successfully accepted or that you decided to reject by hitting the red button.
> 8. in the hisory tab, this is an outgoing call that you made
> 9. this call was a call you did not pick up, but did not reject either... i.e. the caller hung up.
> 10. this appears in the main window besides a contact's name. this means they are offline but they have voicemail active.
> 11. this again is besides a contacts name and means they have call forwarding active
> 12. this will appear on the right hand side of a contacts name and means they have a webcam.